# Setting a variable with multiple rows in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to do something like this in SSIS:

From one SQL table I need to get some id values, I am using a simple sql query:

Select ID from Identifier where value is not null.

I've got this result:

[image]

As a final result I need to generate and set a variable in SSIS with the final value:

`@var = '198','120','ACP','120','PQU'`

Which I need to use later in a odbc expression.

Is this possible in SSIS?

Just to clarify: The image is just a little example of what I can get from the first part of the process. I mean, the number of ID that I need is unknown.

Comment: Yes, use an EXECUTE SQL task and a SQL command that uses FOR XML to concatenate the output.

Comment: Man, any example?, I mean , I'm kind of new in this. Is there a page or a site where I can see the steps?. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple query

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES('186'), ('120'), ('ACP'), ('120'), ('PQU')

DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @ID = CONCAT(COALESCE(@ID + ',''', ''''), ID, '''')
FROM @TEST

SELECT @ID
```

**Result**

```
'186','120','ACP','120','PQU'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the number of Id is variable. It depends on the first part of the process.